# nomethoderror undefined method 'configure' application

Tags: ruby, git, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, push

I am trying to push my app do Heroku. I created ran "heroku create" and that ran through smooth, and it is showing up in my apps on their site. When I run "git push heroku master" I get this error. Everything I have seen pertaining to the same "NoMethodError: undefined method `configure' for ProjectOne::Application" is simply go into the development.rb folder and have this "ProjectOne::Application.configure do".

I am stuck here and can't find anything to help me. As far as I can tell, the no method error is where the push failed and to my knowledge so far, I fixed the problem. If the error is somewhere else in the code or I misunderstand something please let me know! THANKS :)

```
     C:\Users\Devin Miller\project_one>git push heroku master
     Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.132' to the list of     known hosts.
     Initializing repository, done.
     Counting objects: 63, done.
     Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
     Compressing objects: 100% (50/50), done.
     Writing objects: 100% (63/63), 15.70 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
     Total 63 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
###### WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at
 all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile

-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle -
-binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Resolving dependencies...
       Installing minitest 4.7.5
       Installing i18n 0.6.11
       Installing rake 10.3.2
       Installing multi_json 1.10.1
       ....
       Installing jquery-rails 3.0.4
       Installing sass-rails 4.0.3
       Installing turbolinks 1.1.1
       Installing pg 0.15.1
       Installing rails 4.0.8
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Post-install message from rdoc:
       Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri d
ata:
       <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
       = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
       Bundle completed (22.47s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       NoMethodError: undefined method `configure' for #<ProjectOne::Application
:0x007fb53995e890>
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/config/environments/produ
ction.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in req
uire'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_depende
ncy'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engin
e>'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'

       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/config/environment.rb:5:i
n `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in req
uire'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_depende
ncy'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/application.rb:250:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_04896665-39bf-41ee-958e-1afab938608a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/
gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) i
n define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:morning-cliffs-5538.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:morning-cliffs-5538.git'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem, at least in my case. To fix this, run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

At this point I committed my changes and then finally was able to

```
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the top line in production.rb to

```
Rails.application.configure do
```

Or maybe just downcasing Application to application may work.