# How to leverage browser caching in Rails 4?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using GTMetrix to see my site speed and it is showing me this (check below image).

How can I Leverage browser caching to speed up the site loading speed in Rails 4?

To defer parsing JS, I have already put

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

before /html tag.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would recommend using separate web server, like NGINX to set cache headers for .js and .css files, removing the hassle of serving static files from Rails.

If you really wanna go with a pure Rails (app/web)server, the solution is putting this piece of code in `config/environments/production.rb`

**RAILS 5**

```
config.public_file_server.headers = {
  'Cache-Control' => "public, s-maxage=#{365.days.to_i}, maxage=#{180.days.to_i}",
  'Expires' => "#{1.year.from_now.to_formatted_s(:rfc822)}"
}
```

**RAILS 4**

```
config.static_cache_control = "public, s-maxage=#{365.days.to_i}, maxage=#{180.days.to_i}"
```

Comment: Is this Rails 5 ONLY solution ? it looks so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126366/rails-4-2-5-unable-to-upgrade-config-serve-static-files-to-config-public-fi, do we have something similar for R4?

Comment: Recommendation for Rails 4(and 5) is use a CDN. Besides that, set `config.static_cache_control` on `config/environments/production.rb`

Comment: @ErvalhouS could you please post your answer with the CDN?

Comment: Could you ask the separate question showing me what you mean by "answer with the CDN", and comment the link to it? I will be happy to answer it. @KickButtowski

Comment: Is it possible to share your email ?

Comment: you can also use the more idiomatic: `'Cache-Control' => "public, s-maxage=#{365.days.to_i}, maxage=#{180.days.to_i}"`