# Improve HTTP Caching from WebpageTest results Cloudflare/Heroku/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cdn, cloudflare, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to improve my http caching on my website as webpagetest shows a "F" for static content cache. I am using cloudflare as a CDN and rails as my backend. My cache is set to 4 hours, but webpagetest recommends 30 days.

I see that I can adjust the cache with rails as provided there:

[How to leverage browser caching in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741688/how-to-leverage-browser-caching-in-rails-4/41742791#41742791)

However, is it better to adjust it through rails or cloudflare? And if cloudflare, why and how?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to fix cloudflare, as it overrides the Rails settings.

Browser Cache TTL needed to be adjusted under the Cache/configuation/Browser Cache TTL. I set it to a month and it was fixed.